# How does python handle the temporary variables in a conditional statement?

Tags: python, namespaces, garbage-collection, runtime, temporary

Say I have the following code

```
def vc_count(word, low, high):
    if low > high:
        return 0, 0
    v, c = vc_count(word, low+1, high)
    if word[low] in "aeiouAEIOU":
        return v+1, c
    else:
        return v, c+1
```

```
def vc_count(word, low, high):
    if low > high:
        return 0, 0
    v, c = vc_count(word, low+1, high)
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    if word[low] in vowels:
        return v+1, c
    else:
        return v, c+1
```

A string object called 'vowels' is created in the second version while I just wrote "aeiouAEIOU" in the first one.

Will there be a runtime difference or a space usage difference between these two?

Also, will a temporary variable show up in the call stack for the first version? If not, does python just discard it after finishing the in operation?

Comment: The speed difference should be insignificant.  In the second version, `vowels` is simply a local variable that references the string.

Comment: [disassemble](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis) the two versions to see the difference. ... https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces ... https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the rest of the comments, there isn't significant run-time performance. If you do want to check it you could use the `timeit` module to see the differences in the two versions of code provided, it should be fairly marginal difference.

But to answer your question, yes, as soon as that variable which is referenced in the stack (memory) is accessed and used, it's essentially destroyed. However, I would prefer the first version 'better' as it prevents ambiguity within what variables should be actually represent. Sometimes the variable storage will get overwritten by the client and you may not know, and that may lead to undefined behavior of the function which you wouldn't want to happen.